# Howto to receive shell events in a service

Tags: windows, shell, service, events

How do I get events about changed files, directories and media in a Windows service?

Answer (score 2):

If your service is written in a .NET language, you can use System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to monitor file/folder changes.

Comment: I guess if MFC has no direct equivalent of FileSystemWatcher (and I'm not a C++ coder, so I'll defer that question to others) you'd need to invoke a background thread that periodically checked specific parts of the filesystem and alerted the main application if a change were observed.